# Testing Link Function Jasmine input

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test the following directive:

```
module App.Common.Directives {
'use strict';

export class NoSpecialCharacters implements angular.IDirective {

    public restrict = 'A';
    public require = '?ngModel';

    public link = (scope: angular.IScope, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes, ctrl: any) => {

        var clean = (inputValue: string) => {
            if (inputValue == undefined) inputValue = '';
            var cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s-]/gi, '');
            if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                ctrl.$render();
            }
            return cleanInputValue;
        }
        ctrl.$parsers.push(clean);
        clean(scope[attrs['ngModel']]);
    };

}

angular
    .module('app.common.directives')
    .directive('noSpecialCharacters', () => { return new NoSpecialCharacters(); });
}
```

Below is the unit test:

```
var $scope, $compile;

var html = "<div><input type='text' no-special-character ng-model='vm.displayText' /></div>";

beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('app');
});

beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_, _$compile_) => {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $scope.vm = {};

    $compile = _$compile_;


}));

it('should Initialise', () => {
    //
    $scope.vm.displayText = {};
    var el = $compile(html)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
   var x= el.find('input');
    x.val('Some Text*').triggerHandler('keypress');

    $scope.$apply();

    expect(x.val()).toBe('Some Text');
});
```

It appears that link function never gets called, the * is not stripped off.  If I run this on a page it works as expected.

Anyone got any ideas?